# stopword removal using python

Tags: python, string, stop-words

All,

I have some text that I need to clean up and I have a little algorithm that "mostly" works.

```
def removeStopwords(self, data):
    with open(r'stopwords.txt') as stopwords:
        wordList = []
        for i in stopwords:
            wordList.append(i.strip())
        charList = list(data)
        cat = ''.join(char for char in charList if not char in wordList).split()
        return ' '.join(cat)
```

Take the first line on this page. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paragraph and remove all the characters that we are not interested in which in this case are all the non-alphanumeric chars.

> A paragraph (from the Greek paragraphos, "to write beside" or "written beside") is a self-contained unit of a discourse in writing dealing with a particular point or idea. A paragraph consists of one or more sentences.[1][2] The start of a paragraph is indicated by beginning on a new line. Sometimes the first line is indented. At various times, the beginning of a paragraph has been indicated by the pilcrow: ¶.

The output looks pretty good except that some of the words are recombined incorrectly and I am unsure how to correct it.

> A paragraph from the Greek paragraphos to write beside or written beside is a selfcontained unit

Note the word "selfcontained" was "self-contained".

EDIT: Contents of the stopwords file which is just a bunch of chars.

> ! 
>   $ 
>   % 
>   ^ 
>   ,
>   & 
>   * 
>   ( 
>   ) 
>   { 
>   } 
>   [ 
>   ] 
>   <
>
> , 
>   . 
>   / 
>   | 
>   \ 
>   ?
>   ~ 
>   ` 
>   : 
>   ;
>   "

Turns out I don't need a list of words at all because I was only really trying to remove characters which in this case were punctuation marks.

```
        cat = ''.join(data.translate(None, string.punctuation)).split()
        print ' '.join(cat).lower()
```

Comment: What is the contents of stopwords.txt? A list of punctuation symbols, rather then, well, stop words?

Comment: I usually think of "stopword removal" as removing actual words (such as "of" or "the"); but it seems like what you're trying to do here is actually remove specific characters (eg to strip punctuation).  Is that correct?

Comment: @Wooble stopwords is full of non-alphanumeric characters or everything other than letters and numbers.

Comment: @AdamEstrada: Edit your question to include that information.

Comment: The question invites you to remove **all** the non-alphanumeric chars. You are not removing spaces.

Comment: @EdwardLoper I needed to remove a punctuation characters and real stopwords. I figured the list was the best approach at the time but now I am using a combo of the two. http://pastebin.com/rVxvhuBi My stopword list is very close to this one. http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/papers/volume5/lewis04a/a11-smart-stop-list/english.stop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load your stopwords/stopchars in a separate function.

Don't hard-code file names/paths.

Your wordList should be a `set`, not a list.

However if you are working with chars, not words, investigate str.translate.

Comment: Nope...not HW and I need to remove/replace these characters from my data in order to build Jaccard Indices on them.

Answer (score 2):

version 2.x

```
line = 'hello!'
line.translate(None, '!$%') #'hello'
```

[answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939361/remove-specific-characters-from-a-string-in-python)

Comment: +1 Ignore the anonymous downvoter. `str.translate` is the way to go. Maybe change your example to show removing non-alphanumeric chars.

Answer (score -2):

One way to go would be to use the replace method and have an exhaustive list of characters you don't want.

for example:

```
c=['a','h']
a= 'john'
for item in c:
    a =a.replace(item,'')
    print a
```

prints the following:
John
Jon

Comment: Interesting. I get the same results when doing it this way.              for item in wordList:
                data = data.replace(item,'')
            print data