# how to remove all special character

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove specific characters from a string in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939361/remove-specific-characters-from-a-string-in-python)

there's a text:"abc\r egf", I need to filter the '\r', however, I think there's some other special characters I need to filter for other text, maybe '\n', so I want to know whether there's a library can do this job?

Comment: Duplicate: [Remove specific characters from a string in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3939361/938695)

Comment: standard string replace operations will do the job

Answer (score 0):

As [CRUSADER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14228118/how-to-remove-all-special-character#comment19737794_14228118) mentioned, standard string replace operations will do what you want, provided you know what characters you want to remove.

```
text = 'foo\nbar\t\tbaz\r'
new_text = text.replace('\n', '').replace('\t', '').replace('\r', '')
print(new_text)
>>> foobarbaz
```

See [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) for how the function works.

However, using [`re.sub`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/re.html#re.sub) can do this as well, and might even be easier to replace a long list of characters.

```
import re
text = 'foo\nbar\t\tbaz\r'
chars = '[\n\t\r]'
new_text = re.sub(chars, '', text)
print(new_text)
>>> foobarbaz
```