# How to remove specific symbols from a text using python?

Tags: python, list

I have a string like this:

> string = 'This is my text of 2013-02-11, & it contained characters like this! (Exceptional)'

These are the symbols I want to remove from my String.

```
!, @, #, %, ^, &, *, (, ), _, +, =, `, /
```

What I have tried is:

```
listofsymbols = ['!', '@', '#', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')', '_', '+', '=', '`', '/']
exceptionals = set(chr(e) for e in listofsymbols)
string.translate(None,exceptionals)
```

The error is:

> an integer is required

Please help me doing this!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939361/remove-specific-characters-from-a-string-in-python

this may be helpfull!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

```
>>> my_str = 'This is my text of 2013-02-11, & it contained characters like this! (Exceptional)'
>>> my_str.translate(None, '!@#%^&*()_+=`/')
This is my text of 2013-02-11,  it contained characters like this Exceptional
```

Also, please refrain from naming variables that are already built-in names or part of the standard library.

Answer (score 3):

How about this? I've also renamed `string` to `s` to avoid it getting mixed up with the built-in module `string`.

```
>>> s = 'This is my text of 2013-02-11, & it contained characters like this! (Exceptional)'
>>> listofsymbols = ['!', '@', '#', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')', '_', '+', '=', '`', '/']
>>> print ''.join([i for i in s if i not in listofsymbols])
This is my text of 2013-02-11,  it contained characters like this Exceptional
```

Comment: I would have suggested something similar; two minor points: the name "listofsymbols" could be sharpened to "filtersymbols" and the list notation is a bit clumsy, since a simple string also works.

Comment: @guidot. One, names do not matter (with the exceptions of getting mixed up with built-in functions). And strings are immutable, so how would you do your second suggestion?

Comment: filtersymbols IS immutable (the string notation also prevents errors like '@ ' instead of '@') since only used for look-up; and while names don't matter for compilers they do for humans.

Answer (score 0):

Another proposal, easily expandable to more complex filter criteria or other input data type:

```
from itertools import ifilter

def isValid(c): return c not in "!@#%^&*()_+=`/"

print "".join(ifilter(isValid, my_string))
```