# Remove offending characters from strings in list

Tags: python, python-2.7

Sample data to parse (a list of unicode strings):

```
[u'\n', u'1\xa0', u'Some text here.', u'\n', u'1\xa0', u'Some more text here.', 
u'\n', u'1\xa0', u'Some more text here.']
```

I want to remove `\xa0` from these strings.

**EDIT:**
Current Method Not Working:

```
def remove_from_list(l, x):
  return [li.replace(x, '') for li in l]

remove_from_list(list, u'\xa0')
```

I'm still getting the exact same output.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: yes, I'll show my attempts

Comment: Check these, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939361/remove-specific-characters-from-a-string-in-python, http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm

Comment: Which part of this do you not know how to do? How to turn `u'1\xa0'` into `u'10'`? Or how to do the same thing for each element in a list?

Comment: no @abarnert turn it into u'1'

Comment: OK, your problem is _exactly_ the same as the one Rupak linked to: `replace` returns a new string, it doesn't mutate a string in-place.

Comment: @abarnert see updated code, I am doing what the other post recommends for regex and it isn't working

Comment: @DanO'Day: The updated code has either the same problem (`re.sub` _also_ doesn't modify its argument in any way, it just returns a new string) or a related one (rebinding `li` doesn't do anything to whatever `li` used to be bound to).

Comment: Also, you don't need to use `re.sub` instead of `replace` here. The other post only does that as a shortcut to replace multiple different characters at once; you only have one character to replace.

Comment: The new `remove_from_list(list, u'\xa0')` very definitely works. Print out what it returns; the `\xa0` characters are all gone. But if you were expecting it to modify the `list` variable in-place, it's not going to do that. The answer you got it from explains why.

Comment: OK the new list contains single characters

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30151/discussion-between-dan-oday-and-abarnert)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is different in each version of your code. Let's start with this:

```
newli = re.sub(x, '', li)
l[li].replace(newli)
```

First, `newli` is *already* the line you want—that's what `re.sub` does—so you don't need `replace` here at all. Just assign `newli`.

Second, `l[li]` isn't going to work, because `li` is the *value* of the line, not the *index*.

---

In this version, it's a but more subtle:

```
li = re.sub(x, '', li)
```

`re.sub` is returning a new string, and you're assigning that string to `li`. But that doesn't affect anything in the list, it's just saying "`li` no longer refers to the current line in the list, it now refers to this new string".

---

To only way to replace the list elements is to get the index so you can use the `[]` operator. And to get that, you want to use `enumerate`.

So:

```
def remove_from_list(l, x):
  for index, li in enumerate(l):
    l[index] = re.sub(x, '', li)
  return l
```

---

But really, you probably *do* want to use `str.replace`—it's just that you want to use it instead of `re.sub`:

```
def remove_from_list(l, x):
  for index, li in enumerate(l):
    l[index] = li.replace(x, '')
  return l
```

Then you don't have to worry about what happens if `x` is a special character in regular expressions.

---

Also, in Python, you almost never want to modify an object in-place, and also return it. Either modify it and return `None`, or return a new *copy* of the object. So, either:

```
def remove_from_list(l, x):
  for index, li in enumerate(l):
    newli = li.replace(x, '')
    l[index] = newli
```

… or:

```
def remove_from_list(l, x):
  new_list = []
  for li in l:
    newli = li.replace(x, '')
    new_list.append(newli)
  return new_list
```

And you can simply the latter to a list comprehension, as in unutbu's answer:

```
def remove_from_list(l, x):
  new_list = [li.replace(x, '') for li in l]
  return new_list
```

The fact that the second one is easier to write (no need for `enumerate`, has a handy shortcut, etc.) is no coincidence—it's usually the one you want, so Python makes it easy.

---

I don't know how else to make this clearer, but one last try:

If you choose the version that returns a fixed-up new copy of the list instead of modifying the list in-place, your original list will not be modified in any way. If you want to use the fixed-up new copy, you have to use the return value of the function. For example:

```
>>> def remove_from_list(l, x):
...     new_list = [li.replace(x, '') for li in l]
...     return new_list
>>> a = [u'\n', u'1\xa0']
>>> b = remove_from_list(a, u'\xa0')
>>> a
[u'\n', u'1\xa0']
>>> b
[u'\n', u'1']
```

---

The problem you're having with your actual code turning everything into a list of 1-character and 0-character strings is that you don't actually have a list of strings in the first place, you have one string that's a `repr` of a list of strings. So, `for li in l` means "for each character `li` in the string `l`, instead of `for each string`li`in the list`l`.

Comment: For some reason it still isn't working. I am using `return [li.replace(x, '') for li in l]` based on your last line but it still has those characters in place.

Comment: I just updated the answer to show what I did based on this answer.

Comment: This won't modify `l` in-place, it will return a new list with those characters stripped out of each string. You have to print that new list, or assign it to something, or whatever.

Comment: I am, just not showing in my example - I'll update my question to show you.

Answer (score 3):

Another option if you're only interested in ASCII chars (as you mention `characters`, but this also also happens to work for the case of the posted example):

```
[text.encode('ascii', 'ignore') for text in your_list]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [str.replace](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace):

```
>>> items
[u'\n',
 u'1\xa0',
 u'Some text here.',
 u'\n',
 u'1\xa0',
 u'Some more text here.',
 u'\n',
 u'1\xa0',
 u'Some more text here.']
>>> [item.replace(u'\xa0', u'') for item in items]
[u'\n',
 u'1',
 u'Some text here.',
 u'\n',
 u'1',
 u'Some more text here.',
 u'\n',
 u'1',
 u'Some more text here.']
```

Comment: @DanO'Day: _What_ valid characters do you want to maintain that this version doesn't? This retains everything except for `\xa0`, which is exactly what you asked for.

Comment: @DanO'Day: The code didn't change.

Comment: @Matthias my bad, still not working though

Comment: What does "not working" mean? When you run this exact code in your Python interpreter, you get different results that unutbu showed? Or the results unutbu showed are wrong in some way?