# Why doesn't str.translate work in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why does `'a'.translate({'a':'b'})` return `'a'` instead of `'b'`? I'm using Python 3.

Answer (score 61):

The keys used are the ordinals of the characters, not the characters themselves:

```
'a'.translate({ord('a'): 'b'})
```

It's easier to use `str.maketrans`

```
>>> 'a'.translate(str.maketrans('a', 'b'))
'b'

>>> help(str.translate)
Help on method_descriptor:

translate(...)
    S.translate(table) -> str

    Return a copy of the string S, where all characters have been mapped
    through the given translation table, which must be a mapping of
    Unicode ordinals to Unicode ordinals, strings, or None.
    Unmapped characters are left untouched. Characters mapped to None
    are deleted.
```

Comment: Only the key needs to be an ordinal (http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate)

Comment: :( Did I just miss out when jamylak posted maketrans?

Comment: Get this to work with examples from [Remove specific characters from a string in python](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3939381/3491991)