# How to give input permission to accept a name with a space?

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, strip, words

I know that in Python, in order for the program to ignore space you can use `input("something").strip()` but what function do you use for the program to ignore the space if it's in the middle of the word like `ja ck`, also is there a way to combine the name, so if you enter it like `ja ck` it will print `jack`?

Comment: what happens with `jack foo`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace the spaces with blank

```
>>> input("something\n").replace(' ','')
something
ja       ck
'jack'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `str.translate` :

```
input("something").translate(None,' ')
```

if you are in python 3 you need to do the following command:

```
input("something").translate({ord(' '):None})
```

Comment: This is the user input syntax for Python3, but the `str.translate` syntax for Python2. You'll need to do `input("Something").translate(str.maketrans('', '', " "))`

Comment: You can refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17020661/why-doesnt-str-translate-work-in-python-3

Comment: (I always have to look it up to be sure. I know that in Python3 I can use `mapping = str.maketrans({oldlett:newlett for oldlett,newlett in replacements}); some_string.translate(mapping)` but I never remember how it goes together in Python2, so for any SO questions I double check to be sure.

Comment: @AdamSmith ooops! yeah, sure ,thanks for reminding i'll edit the answer!

Answer (score 2):

If you have a single word:

```
input("something").replace(" ","")
```

But `foo bar` will become `foobar` so it really depends on what input is possible, if you are taking more than a single word then it will be a very different proposition.

It might be better to get the user to confirm the input:

```
while True:
   inp = input("Please enter your").replace(" ","")
   confirm = input("You entered {}, enter "r" ro re-enter or any key to continue".format(inp))
   if inp == "r":
       continue
   else:
      # do whatever
```

Comment: Oops, Paddy, Late by 26 secs :)

Answer (score 1):

you could also split the string on spaces, and reassemble it (without spaces):

```
 ''.join("ja ck".split())
```