# Replace values in iterable with values of another iterable to the same value

Tags: python, algorithm

This is a convoluted example, but it shows what I'm attempting to do. Say I have a string:

```
from string import ascii_uppercase, ascii_lowercase, digits
s = "Testing123"
```

I would like to replace all values in `s` that appear in `ascii_uppercase` with "L" for capital letter, all values that appear in `ascii_lowercase` with "l" for lowercase letter, and those in `digits` with "n" for a number.

I'm currently doing:

```
def getpattern(data):
    pattern = ""
    for c in data:
        if c in ascii_uppercase: pattern += "L"; continue
        if c in ascii_lowercase: pattern += "l"; continue
        if c in digits: pattern += "n"; continue
        pattern += "?"
```

However, this is tedious with several more lists to replace. I'm usually better at finding map-type algorithms for things like this, but I'm stumped. I can't have it replace anything that was already replaced. For example, if I run the digits one and replace it with "n", the next iteration might replace that with "l" because "n" is a lowercase letter.

```
getpattern("Testing123") == "Lllllllnnn"
```

Comment: Can you provide an actual example of what you're trying to achieve exactly?  There are numerous ways to map a simple string to another, but your real case may be more constricted. Control characters, like NULL or ACK are well within the ordinal range of 0-255, even though not printable, but if you're dealing with Unicode characters, you may need a different approach.

Comment: The selected answer is ideal. I do not believe I need Unicode, but if I do, I believe I can make it work. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a translation table that maps all upper case letters to `'L'`, all lower case letters to `'l'` and all digits to `'n'`. Once you have such a map, you can pass it to `str.translate()`.

```
from string import ascii_uppercase, ascii_lowercase, digits, maketrans
s = "Testing123"

intab = ascii_uppercase + ascii_lowercase + digits
outtab = ('L' * 26) + ('l' * 26) + ('n' * 10)
trantab = maketrans(intab, outtab)

print s.translate(trantab)
```

Note that in Python 3 there is no `string.maketrans` function. Instead, you get the method from the str object `str.maketrans()`. Read more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17020661/why-doesnt-str-translate-work-in-python-3) and the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans)

I'm not exactly certain of the internals of `str.translate()`, but my educated guess is the mapping creates a length 256 string for each string character. So as it passes over your string, it'll translate `\x00` to `\x00`, `\x01` to `\x01`, etc, but `A` to `L`. That way you don't have to check whether each character is in your translation dictionary. I presume blindly translating all characters with no branches would result to better performance. Print `''.join(chr(i) for i in range(256))` in comparison to see this.

Comment: Interesting, I've never used `maketrans` before. The  trantab variable is 256 bytes long whereas the intab+outtab length is only 124. Is there a method to this madness? It doesn't seem very efficient.

Comment: Also, would I be able to have a default value like I have in the example? I don't mind typing it all out. I could just create a dict with { ascii_uppercase : 'L'  .... etc} and iterate through that. But that is good to know.

Comment: @Goodies I don't understand what you mean by default value. I see no example of this in you question.

Answer (score 1):

They're in different 32-blocks of ASCII, so you can do this:

```
>>> ''.join(' nLl'[ord(c) // 32] for c in s)
'Lllllllnnn'
```

Your example suggests that you don't have other characters, but if you do, this should work:

```
>>> s = "Testing123 and .?#!-+ äöüß"
>>> ''.join(' nLl'[ord(c) // 32] if c <= 'z' and c.isalnum() else '?' for c in s)
'Lllllllnnn?lll????????????'
```

Comment: +1 for creativity. They are strings, but I can't be certain that they are all printable characters. Also, I can't set them to an ord value because they may not all be in that range. I should have specified in OP, though.

Comment: I just added a version that should work for other characters as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you need to process unicode data:

```
import unicodedata

cat = {'Lu':'L', 'Ll':'l', 'Nd':'n'}

def getpattern(data):
    return ''.join(cat.get(unicodedata.category(c),c) for c in data)
```