# A code that replaces a capital y with a capital z and a lowercase y with a lowercase z or the other way around

Tags: python, python-3.x

My task here is to write a function called fix_yz. This function takes a single argument which will be a string. My function returns this string with all of the ys and zs swapped, and all of the Ys and Zs swapped.
What i have done:

```
replace = {"Y":"Z","y":"z","Z":"Y","z":"y"}
def fix_yz(Input):
   replaced=[]
   for yzYZ in Input:
     if yzYZ in replace:
        yzYZ = replace[replaced]
     replaced.append(yzYZ)
  return ''.join(replaced)
```

although i get a error and i dont understand which line to work on.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Your code has indentation errors. Whitespace matters in python, and try not to mix tabs and spaces.

Comment: It says a Type error: unhashable type: "list" @wallyk

Comment: The error is that `yzYZ = replace[replaced]` should be `yzYZ = replace[yzYZ]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has two errors: an indentation error on the return statement, and a wrong variable. You try to index the dictionary by a list.

Fixed version:

```
replace = {"Y":"Z","y":"z","Z":"Y","z":"y"}
def fix_yz(Input):
  replaced=[]
  for yzYZ in Input:
    if yzYZ in replace:
      yzYZ = replace[yzYZ]
    replaced.append(yzYZ)
  return ''.join(replaced)
```

Answer (score 3):

This does exactly what you need:

```
translation_table = str.maketrans({"Y":"Z","y":"z","Z":"Y","z":"y"})

def fix_yz(input_):
    return input_.translate(translation_table)
```

You create a translation table, and then translate everything using it. It is VERY fast regarding execution time, and a very simple solution.

Comment: This does not work for me. The keys of the the table dictionary have to be ordinals, as mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) and here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17020661/why-doesnt-str-translate-work-in-python-3

Comment: The OP wanted the code for Python 3. Maketrans+translate does exactly that. (I updated the question to add maketrans)

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out you simply used the wrong variable in your code, you are trying to lookup using `[replaced]` which is a list not `yzYZ` which is each character in your string:

```
replace = {"Y":"Z","y":"z","Z":"Y","z":"y"}
def fix_yz(Input):
   replaced = []
   for yzYZ in Input:
     if yzYZ in replace:
        yzYZ = replace[yzYZ] # replace[yzYZ]
     replaced.append(yzYZ)
   return ''.join(replaced)
```

You can also simplify your own logic using `dict.get` using each character as the default value if the char is not in your *replace* dict:

```
def fix_yz(inp):
   return ''.join([replace.get(ch, ch) for ch in inp])
```

If you were to use [*str.translate*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.translate) you need to use the ord of each char for your dict mapping:

```
replace = {ord("Y"): "Z", ord("y"): "z", ord("Z"): "Y", ord("z"): "y"}

def fix_yz(inp):
    return inp.translate(replace)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python3 you can do

```
def fix_yz(s):
    return s.translate(str.maketrans("yYzY", "zZyY"))
```

or

```
table = {ord("Y"):"Z",ord("y"):"z",ord("Z"):"Y",ord("z"):"y"}
def fix_yz(s):
    return s.translate(table)
```

in < Python3  it would be

```
from string import maketrans

table = maketrans("yYzY", "zZyY")

def fix_yz(s):
    return s.translate(table)
```