# How to output the special characters from user input if character is not declared on the dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given the specifics of a dictionary (see sample dictionary below) and based on user input, I need to match the per-letter input and the keys then output the values.

I was able to get the output that I want, except that when input includes a special character, it will not display as output (only letters).

Here is the sample dictionary:

```
dict1 = {'a':'q', 'b':'w', 'c':'e', 'd':'r', 'e':'t', 'f':'y', 'g':'u' ...}
```

I tried with the codes below:

```
sentence = input("Enter a sentence:")

result = ''.join([dict1.get(x, ' ') for x in sentence])
print(result)
```

If I input: `abc, de. f-g`
The output: `qwe  rt  yu`

I would like to have this output instead: `qwe, rt. y-q`

Is it possible?

~ EDIT: found my mistake in my code (overlooked something). Was able to fix it. Thanks.

Comment: `key.get(x, x)` == use the mapping if possible, else use the letter as is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [replace multiple characters in string with value from dictionary python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39048559/replace-multiple-characters-in-string-with-value-from-dictionary-python)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use:

```py
result = ''.join([ dict1[x] if x in dict1 else x for x in sentence])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
for k in dict1:
    sentence = sentence.replace(k, dict1[k])
```

**Output** :

```
'qwt, rt. y-u'
```

In python3.8, you can try this list comprehension using walrus operator :

```
sentence = [sentence:=sentence.replace(k, dict1[k]) for k in dict1][-1]
```

**Output** :

```
'qwt, rt. y-u'
```