# Python: Replace single character with multiple values

Tags: python, string, list, replace

I have a string with "?" as placeholders. I need to loop through the string and replace each "?" with the next value in a list.

For example:

```
my_str = "Take the source data from ? and pass to ?;"
params = ['temp_table', 'destination_table']
```

Here's what I've tried, which works:

```
params_counter = 0
for letter in my_str:
    if letter == '?':
        # Overwrite my_str with a new version, where the first ? is replaced
        my_str = my_str.replace('?', params[params_counter], 1)
        params_counter += 1
```

The problem is it seems rather slow to loop through every single letter in the string, multiple times. My example is a simple string but real situations could be strings that are much longer.

**What are more elegant or efficient ways to accomplish this?**

*I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39048559/replace-multiple-characters-in-string-with-value-from-dictionary-python), which is relatively similar, but they're using dictionaries and are replacing multiple values with multiple values, rather than my case which is replacing one value with multiple values.*

Comment: Python has a built-in method for just this task.  Check out the first answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9452108/how-to-use-string-replace-in-python-3-x

Comment: @PhilippeDixon true, but .replace() doesn't give you multiple values to use as the replacements, if I understand it correctly...

Comment: There was no point in looping over every character of your string.  Just do the `.replace()` in a loop; it's not an error if there wasn't actually a `'?'` to replace.

Answer (score 2):

you don't need to iterate, replace will replace the first occcurrence of the string:

a clever solution is to split by the string you are searching, then zipping the list with a list of replacements of length the same and then joining

```
list1 = my_str.split('?')
params = ['temp_table', 'destination_table']
zipped = zip(list1, params)
replaced = ''.join([elt for sublist in zipped for elt in sublist])

In [19]: replaced                                                               
Out[19]: 'Take the source data from temp_table and pass to destination_table'
```

You can use multiple characters strings, which is what would kill your method:

```
my_str = "Take the source data from magicword and pass to magicword;
list1 = my_str.split('magicword') 
params = ['temp_table', 'destination_table'] 
zipped = zip(list1, params)
replaced = ''.join([elt for sublist in zipped for elt in sublist]) 
In [25]: replaced                                                               
Out[25]: 'Take the source data from temp_table and pass to destination_table'
```

Note that if your params are shorter than the number of occurrences of your search string this will cut it

```
IN []my_str = "Take the source data from ? and pass to ?; then do again with ? and to ?"
Out[22]: 'Take the source data from temp_table and pass to destination_table'
```

Also note that the last bit after finding the string is deleted :(, something like

```
replaced = ''.join([elt for sublist in zipped for elt in sublist] + [list1[-1]])
```

Will do the trick

Answer (score 1):

While @E. Serra's answer is a great answer, the comment from @jasonharper made me realize there's a MUCH simpler answer. So incredibly simple that I'm surprised that I completely missed it!

Instead of looping through the string, I should loop through the parameters. That'll allow me to replace the first instance of "?" with the current parameter that I'm looking at. Then I overwrite the string, allowing it to execute correctly on the next iteration.

Unlike the other solution posted, it won't cut off the end of my string either.

```
my_str = "Take the source data from ? and pass to ?;"
params = ['temp_table', 'destination_table']

for item in params:
    query_str = query_str.replace('?', item, 1)
```