# how can i solve this? Python def function

Tags: python

```
def LongestWord(sen): 

  # first we remove non alphanumeric characters from the string
  # using the translate function which deletes the specified characters
  sen = sen.translate(None, "~!@#$%^&*()-_+={}[]:;'<>?/,.|`")

  # now we separate the string into a list of words
  arr = sen.split(" ")
  print(arr)
  # the list max function will return the element in arr
  # with the longest length because we specify key=len
  return max(arr, key=len)

**print LongestWord("Argument goes here")**
```

what's wrong with this line? How can I change it? I can't understand it! It make me really uneasy, cause in Coderbyte.com says that it is true and it work!

Comment: You are calling the function from the function itself it seems. Indent it properly

Comment: @shahidammer No, I think that the asterisks `**` caused it to seem indented but without them it'd be on the outer scope

Comment: what's wrong with this line? which line?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: You need Python 2.7 to run this code, not 3.x. The nr of parameters of the translate function has changed.

Comment: To make it fit for 3.x, take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23175809/str-translate-gives-typeerror-translate-takes-one-argument-2-given-worked-i

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what line you're referring too? Perhaps the last line.

If so you need a parenthesis with the print statement in python 3.x

```
print(LongestWord("Argument goes here"))
```

additionally, string translate works differently in python 3

```
def LongestWord(sen): 

  # first we remove non alphanumeric characters from the string
  # using the translate function which deletes the specified characters
  intab ="~!@#$%^&*()-_+={}[]:;'<>?/,.|`"
  trantab= str.maketrans(dict.fromkeys(intab))

  sen = sen.translate(trantab)

  # now we separate the string into a list of words
  arr = sen.split(" ")
  print(arr)
  # the list max function will return the element in arr

  # with the longest length because we specify key=len
  return max(arr, key=len)

print(LongestWord("Argument. 'Go' @goes here"))
```

## The above worked for me on python 3.6.2

Answer (score 1):

It is working properly but instead of return try

```
print max(arr, key=len)
```

as if you called the function directly without print keyword preceding it won't show the max or you can return both arr, max in single line and print the function output so it would look like this:

```
def LongestWord(sen):
    sen = sen.translate(None, "~!@#$%^&*()-_+={}[]:;'<>?/,.|`")
    arr = sen.split(" ")
    print(arr)
    print max(arr, key=len)


LongestWord("Argument goes here ! @")
```

NOTE : it worked in Python 2.7

IF YOU WOULD LIKE TO USE PYTHON 3.7
 use the following

```
to_remove = sen.maketrans("", "", "~!@#$%^&*()-_+={}[]:;'<>?/,.|`")
sen = sen.translate(to_remove)
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Error starts on line 5 of your code. If I put brackets it give me like this:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/.PyCharmCE2018.2/config/scratches/scratch_1.py", line 8, in <module>
    LongestWord("Argument goes here ! @")
  File "/root/.PyCharmCE2018.2/config/scratches/scratch_1.py", line 2, in LongestWord
    sen = sen.translate(None, "~!@#$%^&*()-_+={}[]:;'<>?/,.|`")
TypeError: translate() takes exactly one argument (2 given)

Comment: Make sure you are using python version 2.7 or you can make it like this of you want to use version higher than 3.5                        
 to_remove = sen.maketrans("", "", "~!@#$%^&*()-_+={}[]:;'<>?/,.|`")
sen = sen.translate(to_remove)