# Remove the 'S' from the end of words in a list (Python, Pandas)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Say I have a list like this:

```
Words
One
Twos
Threes
Four
Fives
...
Thousand
```

Is there a relatively simple way to remove the 'S' from the end of the words?  So it would become:

```
Words
One
Two
Three
Four
Five
...
Thousand
```

Comment: Show us what you have done so far.

Comment: Sorry for the lazy question!  Unfortunately I'm home now so I'll post what I've tried once I am in front of my computer tomorrow

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939361/remove-specific-characters-from-a-string-in-python and you can use string[-1:] to get the last character. Do some magic and sort through the lines with "s" on the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.where` to test if the last character is an 's' and if so remove it, otherwise use the existing value, this will be vectorised and much faster than a list comprehension:

```
In [14]:

df['Words'] = np.where(df['Words'].str[-1] == 's', df['Words'].str[:-1], df['Words'])
df
Out[14]:
      Words
0       One
1       Two
2     Three
3      Four
4      Five
5  Thousand
```

An alternative method which is likely to be even faster is to use `loc` and your condition to only strip the last character where it contains a trailing s, all other rows are left untouched:

```
In [18]:

df.loc[df['Words'].str[-1] == 's','Words'] = df['Words'].str[:-1]
df
Out[18]:
      Words
0       One
1       Two
2     Three
3      Four
4      Five
5  Thousand
```

Comment: Quick follow up -- would this method still work if I was dealing with a multiword word string i.e.: "Twos and Threes"

Comment: No, of that you'd have to apply a regex or a lambda to test each word for that character and strip it

Comment: ahhh i was afraid of that -- ok I'll see what I Can do!