# how to remove characters from items in a list, using another list as reference

Tags: python, list, remove-if

I am trying to remove specific characters from items in a list, using another list as a reference. Currently I have:

```
forbiddenList = ["a", "i"]
tempList = ["this", "is", "a", "test"]
sentenceList = [s.replace(items.forbiddenList, '') for s in tempList]
print(sentenceList)
```

which I hoped would print:

```
["ths", "s", "test"]
```

of course, the forbidden list is quite small and I could replace each individually, but I would like to know how to do this "properly" for when I have an extensive list of "forbidden" items.

Comment: I like to do these things with a regex - regex's even have classes which are helpful - (e.g trying to remove all non printable chars)

Comment: anyway this is a dup - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939361/remove-specific-characters-from-a-string-in-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a nested list comprehension.

```
>>> [''.join(j for j in i if j not in forbiddenList) for i in tempList]
['ths', 's', '', 'test']
```

It seems like you also want to remove elements if they become empty (as in, all of their characters were in `forbiddenList`)? If so, you can wrap the whole thing in even another list comp (at the expense of readability)

```
>>> [s for s in [''.join(j for j in i if j not in forbiddenList) for i in tempList] if s]
['ths', 's', 'test']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> templist = ['this', 'is', 'a', 'test']
>>> forbiddenlist = ['a', 'i']
>>> trans = str.maketrans('', '', ''.join(forbiddenlist))
>>> [w for w in (w.translate(trans) for w in templist) if w]
['ths', 's', 'test']
```

This is a Python 3 solution using [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) and [`str.maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans). It should be fast.

You can also do this in Python 2, but the interface for [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) is slightly different:

```
>>> templist = ['this', 'is', 'a', 'test']
>>> forbiddenlist = ['a', 'i']
>>> [w for w in (w.translate(None, ''.join(forbiddenlist)) 
...         for w in templist) if w]
['ths', 's', 'test']
```