# How to replace tabs to spaces

Tags: python, string

I've been given the task to create a function that takes a string and does the following:

- replaces each tab with a space
- turns all letters lowercase
- removes characters:   !@#$%^&*()_+-=[]{}\|`~;:'"<>?,./

I already cracked the lowercase part by using `msg.lower()`, but I'm mostly stuck on the tabs to spaces part.

Any suggestions?

Comment: As for the last part: [Remove specific characters from a string in python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3939361)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use series of `re.sub` functions.

```
>>> def clean(s):
        return re.sub(r'[-!@#$%^&*()_+=\[\]{}\|`~;:\'"<>?,./]', '',re.sub(r'\t', ' ', s)).lower()

>>> clean('FOO[sdFD]-+()!-')
'foosdfd'
>>> clean('Music    [()]-+~:;"  @#%&*Foo')
'music  foo'
```

**Explanation:**

- `re.sub(r'\t', ' ', s)` would turn all the tabs to spaces.
- re.sub(r'[-!@#$%^&*()_+=[]{}\|`~;:\'"<>?,./]', '',re.sub(r'\t', ' ', s)) removes all the mentioned special chars from the resultant string.
- `.lower()` helps to turn all uppercase letters to lowercase letters.