# Split word in Python

Tags: python, regex, string

I am trying to use `re.split` in python. I want to remove all these characters like `" , ; < > { } [ ] / \ ? !` .I am trying to do something like this-

```
re.split("[, \_!?,;:-]+", word)
```

How can I add characters like `"` `(` `)` or `<` `>` `'` so that they can also be removed?

**Edit**

```
re.split('\W+',word)
```

This works fine but it is not removing underscore symbol. How can I also remove underscore?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939361/remove-specific-characters-from-a-string-in-python

Comment: Are you trying to remove all non-alphanumeric characters?  For instance, you end up with only characters a-z, A-Z and 0-9?

Comment: @sberry Yes, see my edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
re.split('\W+|\_', word)
```

Also just remove them:

```
re.sub('\W+|\_', '', word)
```

Take a look at [the document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

checkout the str.translate function for example in python 2.6+

```
line = line.translate(None, " ?.!/;:")
```

or in python 3+

```
line = line.translate(" ?.!/;:")
```

see [Remove specific characters from a string in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939361/remove-specific-characters-from-a-string-in-python)