# Remove extra comma from the string

Tags: python-2.7

I can't able to delete the extra comma from the below list of strings

```
[',156,151,2016-06-07',',160,147,2016-03-16',',99,91,2016-06-11']
```

I tried to use join and delete but it didn't work

expecting the result like below

```
['156,151,2016-06-07','160,147,2016-03-16','99,91,2016-06-11']
```

please help me...thanks in advance

Comment: For anyone else reading, the "extra comma" is the very first one from here => `[',`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove specific characters from a string in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939361/remove-specific-characters-from-a-string-in-python)

Comment: There appears to be a leading comma for each one actually

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list-comprehension:

```
>>> l = [',156,151,2016-06-07',',160,147,2016-03-16',',99,91,2016-06-11']
>>> l = [i.lstrip(',') for i in l]
>>> l
['156,151,2016-06-07', '160,147,2016-03-16', '99,91,2016-06-11']
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `str.replace`:

```
newArr = []
for line in arr:
    newArr.append(line.replace(',', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use list comprehension for the same :-

```
>>> l= [',156,151,2016-06-07',',160,147,2016-03-16',',99,91,2016-06-11']
>>> [i.lstrip(',') for i in l]
['156,151,2016-06-07', '160,147,2016-03-16', '99,91,2016-06-11']
```