# Unable to kick out unwanted characters from a long string

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, replace

How can I remove unwanted characters from a long text using `.replace()` or any of that sort. Symbols I wish to kick out from the text are `',',{,},[,]` (commas are not included). My existing text is:

```
{'SearchText':'319 lizzie','ResultList':[{'PropertyQuickRefID':'R016698','PropertyType':'Real'}],'TaxYear':2018}
```

I tried with the below code:

```
content='''
{'SearchText':'319 lizzie','ResultList':[{'PropertyQuickRefID':'R016698','PropertyType':'Real'}],'TaxYear':2018}
'''
print(content.replace("'",""))
```

Output I got:  [btw, If i keep going like .replace().replace() with different symbols in it then it works but i wish to do the same in a single instance if its possible]

```
{SearchText:319 lizzie,ResultList:[{PropertyQuickRefID:R016698,PropertyType:Real}],TaxYear:2018}
```

I wish i could use replace function like `.replace("',{,},[,]","")`. However, I'm not after any solution derived from `regex`. String manipulation is what I expected. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you considered using regex?

Comment: Thanks Mad Physicist for your comment. Actually, i was not after any solution derived from regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
content=r"{'SearchText':'319 lizzie','ResultList':[{'PropertyQuickRefID':'R016698','PropertyType':'Real'}],'TaxYear':2018}"

igno = "{}[]''´´``''"
cleaned = ''.join([x for x in content if x not in igno])

print(cleaned)
```

PyFiddle 3.6:

```
SearchText:319 lizzie,ResultList:PropertyQuickRefID:R016698,PropertyType:Real,TaxYear:2018
```

In 2.7 I get an error:

> Non-ASCII character '\xc2' in file main.py on line 3, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details

wich can be fixed by adding `# This Python file uses the following encoding: utf-8` as 1st line in source code -  which then gives identical output.

Comment: Yes, it does the trick. Btw, ain't it possible to do the same using `.replace()` function with multiple characters in it? Gonna accept it in a while.

Comment: @topto you can also use string.transform - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/3939381/7505395 but with unicode it seems to be a pita - so i would stick to list comprehension: `for a man with a hammer, all problems tend to look like nails` ;)