# Python how to remove equal sign "=" in strings?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python how to remove = in strings?

```
a = 'bbb=ccc'

a.rstrip('=')
# returns 'bbb=ccc'

a.rstrip('\=')
# alse returns 'bbb=ccc'
```

how to match `=` ?

Comment: You should probably take some time to [read the `rstrip` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip), and learn what it actually do.

Comment: I misunderstood. thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove specific characters from a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939361/remove-specific-characters-from-a-string-in-python)

Answer (score 4):

You can replace it with an empty string:

```
a.replace("=", "")
```

For reference:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `replace` method (easiest):

```
a = 'bbb=ccc'
a.replace('=', '')
```

or the `translate` method (probably faster on large amounts of data):

```
a = 'bbb=ccc'
a.translate(None, '=')
```

or the `re.sub` method (most powerful, i.e. can do much more):

```
import re
re.sub('=', '', 'aaa=bbb')
```

Answer (score 0):

`strip` removes characters **from the beginning** and **from the end** of the string!
From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=strip#str.strip):

```
 str.strip([chars]) 

Return a copy of the string with leading and trailing characters removed.
```

Since you "=" is neither at the beggining nor at the end of your string, you can't use `strip` for your purpose. You need to use `replace`.

```
a.replace("=", "")
```