# How to split using mutli-character delimiters in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I have a string :

```
string = 'i-phone is popular - many people like it (user-friendly system, fast, good support)'
```

How to use regular expression to split it as:

```
split_string = ['i-phone', 'is', 'popular', 'many', 'people', 'like',  'it', 'user-friendly', 'system', 'fast', 'good', 'support']
```

The problem is that `-` contains 2 spaces and 1 hyphen.

I tried:
    split_string = re.split('[() - ]', string)
but I got:

```
['i-phone', 'is', 'popular', '-', 'many', 'people', 'like', 'it', '', 'user-friendly', 'system,', 'fast,', 'good', 'support', '']
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hope its a duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939361/remove-specific-characters-from-a-string-in-python/21357173]

Comment: Thanks, yogi. But I cannot make it. Can you show me? Thanks.

Comment: May be some thing like [`\s+(?:[()-]\s*)?|[,()]\s*`](https://regex101.com/r/ltNjjh/1)

Comment: @John What do you mean you "cannot make it"? SO is not a "do my work for me" service. It exists to help you fill in *missing knowledge*, and it's up to you to figure out exactly what knowledge it is that you're missing, especially once you have been given a resource to look into.

Comment: Gurman, thank you. The list obtained is `['i-phone', 'is', 'popular', 'many', 'people', 'like', 'it', 'user-friendly', 'system', 'fast', 'good', 'support', '']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this regex to split:

```
\s+(?:[()-]\s*)?|[,()]\s*
```

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ltNjjh/2)**

**Explanation**

- `\s+` - matches 1+ white-spaces
- `(?:[()-]\s*)?` - matches either `(`, `)`, `-` followed by 0+ occurrences of white-space. The `?` at the end makes this subpart optional
- `|` - OR
- `[,()]\s*` - matches either `,` or `(` or `)` followed by 0+ whitespaces

Comment: Gurman, it works. Thank you very much for your answer and explanation.