# How to remove characters in one strong from another string

Tags: python, python-2.7

For homework I am trying to strip a set of characters inputted from the user from a sentence inputted by a user. This is the code that I have come up with so far using Python 2.7:

```
    sentence = raw_input("Please write a sentence. ")
    remove = raw_input("Please input characters to remove from sentence. ")

    remove = remove.strip(" ") # in case user added spaces
    sentence = sentence.strip(remove)
    print sentence
```

Comment: Have you thought about utilizing a for loop to remove characters one at a time? You could also use the regex module (`re.sub`, for example) as another solution

Comment: `str.strip()` only removes the characters from the start or end of the string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove specific characters from a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939361/remove-specific-characters-from-a-string-in-python)

Comment: I could try using a loop, perhaps that can work for me. we have not learnt regex module yet, so that may be outside of the scope of the lesson.

Comment: I do not see the similarity between what I am doing and the possible duplicate @GrantWilliams

Comment: @PierreRoodman from the answer selected in the possible duplicate
`removed = re.sub('[!@#$]', '', sentence)` you'd have to update the character class to match your input `remove` variable though

Comment: Thank you @GrantWilliams I will definitely research on the regex module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as HUAN said in his answer, `sentence.strip` will only remove characters from the beginning and the end of the sentence string, to remove letters in between you should use `sentence.replace`, here's your code I rewrote to use `replace`, I also used a for loop to remove multiple characters, so if the user input something like "hw" the sentence "hello world" becomes "ello orld":

```
sentence = raw_input("Please write a sentence. ")
remove = raw_input("Please input characters to remove from sentence. ")

remove = remove.strip(" ") # in case user added spaces
for c in remove:
    sentence = sentence.replace(c,"")
print sentence
```

Comment: can you explain how "c in remove" works I posted an answer already for the a while loop that I used.

Comment: c is just a variable, you can name it anything else, on each loop the c variable stores a character of the string remove, python supports string indexing so we can treat it as an iterable,so we can iterate through it just like a list, so in the first loop c stores the first character of the string, and the next loop, c stores the second character in the string, and so on until there are no more characters.

Comment: Syntax. for iterating_var in sequence: statements(s)

Comment: Thank you @Redivider , this was very informative. Much simpler method.

Comment: You're Welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a `regex` and leveraging `character class` as follows:

```
import re
sentence = raw_input("Please write a sentence. ")
remove = raw_input("Please input characters to remove from sentence. ")
regex = "[" + re.escape(remove) + "]"
sentence = re.sub(regex, "", sentence)
print(sentence)
```

It takes the user input and escapes anything that is a special regex character.  That way if a user puts in `.*` it won't have unexpected results.  Then it substitutes any of those characters with `""` which is nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sentence.replace(remove, "")` to replace specific characters with an empty string, or in other words, remove a specific string.

In your code, `sentence.strip(remove)` didnt work because it only removes words from the *front* and the *end* of the of the string.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me had to use a loop:

```
   sentence = raw_input("Please write a sentence. ")
   remove = raw_input("Please input characters to remove from sentence. ")

   remove = remove.replace(" ", "")
   i = 0
   while i < len(remove):
       sentence = sentence.replace(remove[i], "")
       i += 1
   print sentence
```