# How can you delete all non-letters from a list?

Tags: python, list

I want that you can give a string (Userinput) and then I want to delete all characters that aren't letters (so a-z and A-Z are the only ones which stay in the string).

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What have you tried? This is very easy to do, you surely can give it a try!

Comment: as highlighted by @ForceBru,  you can also use regex.

Comment: Possible [Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939361/remove-specific-characters-from-a-string-in-python)

Comment: Look into the regular expression module (import re).  re.sub("[^A-za-z]","",YourString) or something like that should do the trick.

Comment: @Kaiwen Chen. Isn't there a way to delete all non-letters, in the other question, you have to write the characters you want to delete.

Comment: Learn how to use regex. Here is the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)  hint: [A-Za-z]

Comment: Is your input a list or a string?

Comment: @xskxzr. A string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use Python's `re` (regular expression) module. More specifically you could try using the `re.sub` method. Here is a quote from the official documentation:

> `re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)`
>     Return the string obtained by replacing the leftmost non-overlapping occurrences of 
>     `pattern` in `string` by the replacement `repl`.

For example, if your string is `'God damn 47'`, you could do `re.sub('[0-9]', '', 'God damn 47')` and get `'God damn '`. This will substitute any digit within the string with `''` (empty string) which is equivalent to deleting them. Remember to import the `re` module with the statement `import re`.