# How to remove "." and "-" from a string?

Tags: python

I am trying to copy a string from a website and paste it into another program. But I first have to remove the "." and "-" from the string. Ex. it is "123.345.322.22-00" but I need it to be "1233453222200".

I have tried using replace() and replace and join(). It is python 3.7.2

```
#copy number
pg.moveTo(238,419)

pg.click(238,419,clicks=3)
pg.hotkey('ctrl','c')

cep = pyperclip.paste()

print(cep)



cepnovo= [cep.split(".").join("")]


print(cepnovo)
```

I get `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'join'`

actual result `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'join'`

Expected is to output the string without `"."` and `"-"`.

Comment: `join` is a `str` method that takes an iterable, not a `list` method: `"".join(cep.split("."))`

Comment: Use `replace`: `cep.replace('.').replace('-')` or `re.sub`: `import re ; cep = re.sub('[\.-]', '', cep)`

Comment: "I have tried using replace()" Please show us that code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove specific characters from a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939361/remove-specific-characters-from-a-string-in-python)

Answer (score 5):

You say you tried `replace`, but fail to give what happens. Because this works:

```
>>> "123.45-6".replace(".", "").replace("-", "")
'123456'
```

Comment: Or to perform the replacement as a single pass, make a translation table up front (outside the function so you don't rebuild it over and over): `remove_dot_hyphen = str.maketrans("", "", ".-")`, then on each use, `"123.45-6".translate(remove_dot_hyphen)`. No real performance difference for short strings with only a couple characters to delete, but for longer strings, or for deleting more than two characters, `str.translate` is often faster.

Answer (score 0):

`list`s don't have the `join` method, strings do

you could use this workaround: (if you're keen on using `split` and `join`)

```
list = cep.split(".")

cepnovo = "".join(list)
```

always check the documentation about which methods are provided on each data type... they may be different from language to language

Answer (score 0):

The exception you obtain is selfdescribing. Try this line:

```
cepnovo= "".join(cep.split("."))
```

If you want just to get the numeric symbols, instead of removing other symbols you can try finding the numeric ones

```
import re

text = "4332.24324.blablabl.45353-fewfe-32232"
print("".join(re.findall(r"\d+", text)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try list comprehension and join

```
str = '123.345.322.22-00'
result = ''.join([x for x in str if x not in ['.', '-']])
```

Answer (score -1):

This sounds like a job for regex, if you are for sure parsing a string. Use it by `import re` and this should get rid of all the dots and dashes and replace them with nothing.

```
new_cep = re.sub('[.-]', '', cep)
```

Comment: Not the down-voter, but getting regexes involved for something this simple is overkill (and *much* slower than simple `str.replace` or `str.translate` equivalents). It's also risky for folks who don't know regex well, as adding a new character after the hyphen would *dramatically* change behavior.