# Remove unnecessary value from an element and make a new element in list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
dics = []
```

The following shows the values in the list of dics:

```py
["['Definition.", "', 'Exceptions.", "', 'Compelled Disclosure."]
```

But, what I am wondering is how I can remove the unnecessary values from the list such as:

- `['` for Definition.
- `', '` for Exceptions.
- `','` for Compelled Disclosure.
  I'd like to define the list  to be like this:

```py
["Definition.", "Exceptions.", "Compelled Disclosure."]
```

without unnecessary data. It would be really appreciated if you can help with any. Thanks.

Comment: Use a regex and split your string?

Comment: The question you should be asking is how did your data get like this? You should fix the problem upstream.

Comment: How did you get that list? If that was a string that you `.split`ted on whitespace, It might be easier to parse it properly in the first place.

Comment: looks like a botched case of json conversion gone really wrong.

Comment: [How to turn a string representation of a list into a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/convert-string-representation-of-list-to-list).

Comment: List comprehension with any suggestions from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3939381/6779606) would work well.

Comment: Hacky fix would be to join this back together as a string and then use `literal_eval`: `literal_eval("".join(["['Definition.", "', 'Exceptions.", "', 'Compelled Disclosure."]) + "']")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
v = ["['Definition.", "', 'Exceptions.", "', 'Compelled Disclosure."]
s = "|".join(v)
undesired = "[,' "

for u in undesired:
    s = s.replace(u, "")

print(s.split("|"))
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. By the way, for "Compelled Disclosure" it shows like this CompelledDisclosure, without the space.

Comment: Removing the space from undesired and run all resulting elements throught strip() instead will take care of that

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a combination of `filter` and `isalpha` method to rule out every character of each word that is not a letter:

```
dics = ["['Definition.", "', 'Exceptions.", "', 'Compelled Disclosure."]
dics = [(''.join(filter(lambda letter: letter.isalpha() or letter==' ',elem))+elem[-1]).strip() for elem in dics]
print(dics)
```

Output:

```
['Definition.', 'Exceptions.', 'Compelled Disclosure.']
```