# Replace multiple characters using re.sub

Tags: python, regex, string, python-2.7

```
s = "Bob hit a ball!, the hit BALL flew far after it was hit."
```

I need to get rid of the following characters from s

```
!?',;.
```

How to achieve this with re.sub?

```
re.sub(r"!|\?|'|,|;|."," ",s) #doesn't work. And replaces all characters with space
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong with this?

Comment: Are you really using Python 2?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove specific characters from a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939361/remove-specific-characters-from-a-string-in-python)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that `.` matches all characters, not the literal `'.'`. You want to escape that also, `\.`.

But a better way would be to not use the OR operator `|`, but simply use a character group instead:

```
re.sub(r"[!?',;.]", ' ', s)
```

Comment: re.sub(r"!|\?|'|,|;|\."," ",s)
I forgot that . is a match all character. Thanks
I have added a backslack to the '.'
It works fine now

Comment: @Wkhan Please consider using the second option I provided, it is more readable and much more efficient (only 60 steps vs. 338 steps!) see [here](https://regex101.com/r/haaFjr/1)