# Using a List as 1 argument in replace()

Tags: python, string, list

Trying to solve.

I have a string from a user input. And I want to reomove all special characters from a list = 
[',', '.', '"', '\'', ':',]

using the replace function I´m able to remove one by one. using somethin like:

```
string = "a,bhc:kalaej jff!"
string.replace(",", "")
```

but I want to do remove all the special chr. in one go. I have tried:

```
unwanted_specialchr = [',', '.', '"', '\'', ':',]
string = "a,bhc:kalaej jff!"
string.replace(unwanted_specialchr, "")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove specific characters from a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939361/remove-specific-characters-from-a-string-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

figured it out:

```
def remove_specialchr(string):
    unwanted_specialchr = [',', '.', '"', '\'', ':',]
    for chr in string:
        if chr in  unwanted_specialchr:
            string = string.replace(chr, '')
    return string
```

Comment: You can get a speedup out of this by converting `unwanted_specialchr` to a set. Replace the square brackets with curly braces. It still may not be optimal, because you have to do O(len(unwanted_specialchar)) `replace` operations, which pass over the entire string.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
import re

unwanted_specialchr = [',', '.', '"', '\'', ':',]
string = "a,bhc:kalaej jff!"
re.sub(f'[{"".join(unwanted_specialchr)}]', '', string)
```

output:

```
'abhckalaej jff!'
```

or you could use:

```
''.join(c for c in string if c not in unwanted_specialchr)
```

output:

```
'abhckalaej jff!'
```

Comment: when i try to define a code using def code(): I cant get it to return the editet string, any tips?

Comment: Do you want to write a function?

Comment: you should have a return statement to return something 0_O

Answer (score 1):

Well i think that your solution could be better with the optimization:

```
def remove_specialchr(string):
    specialChr = {',', '.', '"', '\'', ':'}
    stringS = ''
    for chr in string:
        if chr not in specialChr:
            stringS += it
    return stringS
```

Comment: But it has to construct a new string every time you do a `+=`. Python strings are immutable.