# remove certain charicters from a string python

Tags: python, python-3.x

is there a function in python that does something like this:

input:

```
text = "s.om/e br%0oken tex!t".remove(".","/","%","0","!")
print(text)
```

output:

```
some broken text
```

The only thing that i know that can kinda to this is `.replace("x", "")` and that takes way too long to get rid of lots of different charicters. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove specific characters from a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939361/remove-specific-characters-from-a-string-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regex module `re` to replace them all. The `[]` means any character in it :

```
text = re.sub("[./%0!]", "", "s.om/e br%0oken tex!t")
```

Comment: Sorry, my typing speed is a bit slow I was writing my answer while yours got posted now what to do about my answer?

Comment: @WasifHasan You can keep it, there lots of posts where multiple answers are same, or delete it, as you wish

Answer (score 0):

You might use `str.maketrans` combined with `.translate`; example:

```
t = str.maketrans("","","./%0!")
text = "s.om/e br%0oken tex!t"
cleantext = text.translate(t)
print(cleantext)  # print(cleantext)
```

maketrans accept 3 arguments, every n-th character from first will be replaced with n-th character from second, all characters present in third will be jettisoned. In this case we only want to jettison so 1st and 2nd arguments are empty `str`s.

Alternatively you might use comprehension as follows:

```
text = "s.om/e br%0oken tex!t"
cleantext = ''.join(i for i in text if i not in "./%0!")
print(cleantext)  # some broken text
```

Comment: The answer is correct, but I'd say this is not the goal of translate, `re.sub` is much more dedicated ;)

Comment: @azro: do as you wish but remember that even inside `[` and `]` some characters have special meaning for `re.sub`, so do *not* be surprised if after trying to remove `^.` everything excluding `.` will be gone

Comment: Thanks for you concern I know regex syntax pretty well ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is a module named re which is used in Regular expressions. You can use its sub function to replace or substitute characters from a string. Then you can try like this:

```
from re import sub
text = sub("[./%0!]","","The string")
print(text)
```

Regex details: Character class of . / % 0 ! if these are found in string replace them with a blank string and later print the text variable.