# Python remove some ascii characters in list

Tags: python

Input:

```
list=["@stellar I loo#oo)oooovvvv;vveee my K!" , "rl I loo#os#"]
```

I want like this output:

```
"stellar I loooooooovvvvvveee my K", "rl I looos"
```

How can i delete some ascii characters in list? **( not only #,!,@,) )**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove specific characters from a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939361/remove-specific-characters-from-a-string-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map that list, with regex replace.

```py
import re

list=["@stellar I loo#oo)oooovvvv;vveee my K!" , "rl I loo#os#"]
result = list(map(lambda x: re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9\s]', '', x), list))

print(result)
```

Comment: it works properly. i have a short question, if inputs are  "I'have"  or "I'll" output -> "ihave" or "ill" how can i pass like this word ?

Comment: You can add \' to regex pattern [^A-Za-z0-9\s\'] it will ignore apostrophe.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `regex`:

```
import re

regex = re.compile('[^a-zA-Z\ ]')

my_strings = =["@stellar I loo#oo)oooovvvv;vveee my K!" , "rl I loo#os#"]

print([regex.sub("", s) for s in my_strings])
>>> ['stellar I loooooooovvvvvveee my K', 'rl I looos']
```

This will replace all non-letter characters by an empty string (therefore deleting it)

You can use `re.compile('[^0-9a-zA-Z\ ]')` if you want to keep numbers

Answer (score 1):

see below:

```
my_list=["@stellar I loo#oo)oooovvvv;vveee my K!" , "rl I loo#os#"]
chars_to_remove = ['!','@']
for word in my_list:
    for char in word:
        if char in chars_to_remove:
            word.replace(char, '')
```