# Python vowel eater

Tags: python

Good evening everyone..... i wrote a vowel eater program with the code below

```
wordWithoutVowels = ""
userWord = input("Please Enter a word: ")
userWord = userWord.upper()
for letter in userWord:
    if letter == 'A':
        continue
    elif letter == 'E':
        continue
    elif letter == 'I':
        continue
    elif letter == 'O':
        continue
    elif letter == 'U':
        continue
    else:
        print(letter)
```

It run fine but i want to use concatenation operation to ask python to combine selected letters into a longer string during subsequent loop turns, and assign it to the wordWithoutVowels variable.....
I really appreciate any help or suggestions thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove specific characters from a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939361/remove-specific-characters-from-a-string-in-python)

Comment: `eater = lambda s: ''.join(filter(lambda c: c.upper() not in {'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'}, s))`

Comment: Thanks but I just need a simple concatenation in the loop @ Janez Kuhar

Answer (score 3):

is this what you need?

```
wordWithoutVowels = ""
userWord = input("Please Enter a word: ")
userWord = userWord.upper()
for letter in userWord:
    if letter == 'A':
        word = letter
        continue
    elif letter == 'E':
        continue
    elif letter == 'I':
        continue
    elif letter == 'O':
        continue
    elif letter == 'U':
        continue
    else:
        wordWithoutVowels+=letter

print(wordWithoutVowels)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach. You can prepare a set of vowels you want to filter-out before-hand and then use `str.join()` to obtain you string:

```
userWord = input("Please Enter a word: ")
vowels = set('aeiou')

wordWithoutVowels = ''.join(character for character in userWord if not character.lower() in vowels)

print(wordWithoutVowels)
```

Prints (for example):

```
Please Enter a word: Hello World
Hll Wrld
```

Comment: Why not simple use `replace()`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry I didn't read the original post (OP) more carefully. Poster clearly asked for a way to do this by concatenation in a loop. So instead of excluding vowels, we want to include the good characters. Or instead of looking for membership, we can look for not in membership.

```
wordWithoutVowels = ""
userWord = input("Please Enter a word: ")

vowels = 'aAeEiIoOuU'

wordWithoutVowels = '' # initialize to empty string

for letter in userWord:
    if letter not in vowels:
        wordWithoutVowels += letter  # equivalent to wordWithoutVowels = wordWithoutVowels + letter

print(wordWithoutVowels)
```

```
Please Enter a word: Hello World
Hll Wrld
```

Answer (score 1):

or you can try this:

```
wordWithoutVowels = ""

user = input("Enter a word: ")
userWord  = user.upper()


for letter in userWord:
    if letter == "A":
        continue
    elif letter == "E":
        continue
    elif letter == "O":
        continue
    elif letter == "I":
        continue
    elif letter == "U":
        continue
    else:
        wordWithoutVowels += letter

print(wordWithoutVowels)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using str.replace() seems like a natural way to go for a problem like this

**Brute Force**

Just go through all of the vowels. And if they exist in input string, replace them

```
wordWithoutVowels = ""
userWord = input("Please Enter a word: ")
userWord = userWord.upper()

# make a copy of userWord
output = userWord

# replace vowels
output = output.replace('A', '') # replace A with empty string
output = output.replace('E', '') # replace E with empty string
output = output.replace('I', '') # replace I with empty string
output = output.replace('O', '') # replace O with empty string
output = output.replace('U', '') # replace U with empty string

print(output)
```

```
Please Enter a word: Hello World
HLL WRLD
```

**Use a loop**

This is a little more elegant. And you won't have to convert the input to uppercase.

```
wordWithoutVowels = ""
userWord = input("Please Enter a word: ")

# make a copy of userWord
output = userWord

# replace vowels
vowels = 'aAeEiIoOuU'
for letter in vowels:
    output = output.replace(letter, '') # replace letter with empty string

print(output)
```

```
Please Enter a word: Hello World
Hll Wrld
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I think it's the easiest way:

```
word_without_vowels = ""
user_word = input("Enter a word")
user_word = user_word.upper()

for letter in user_word:
    # Complete the body of the loop.
    if letter in ("A","E","I","O","U"):
        continue
    word_without_vowels+=letter
print(word_without_vowels)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
user_word =str(input("Enter a Word"))
# and assign it to the user_word variable.
user_word = user_word.upper()
vowels = ('A','E','E','I','O','U')
for letter in user_word:
    if letter in vowels:
        continue
    elif letter == vowels:
        letter = letter - vowels
    else:
        print(letter)
```

Comment: Care to include an explanation for the code so we can interpret your solution?

Answer (score 0):

A one liner that does what you need is:

`wordWithoutVowels = ''.join([ x for x in userWord if x not in 'aeiou'])`

or the equivalent:

`wordWithoutVowels = ''.join(filter(lambda x : x not in 'aeiou', userWord))`

The code is creating a list containing the letters in the string that are not vowels and then joining them into a new string.

You just need to figure out how to handle the lower/capital cases. You could do `x.lower() not in 'aeiou'`, check if `x is in 'aeiouAEIOU'`, ... you have plenty of choices.

Answer (score 0):

```
user_word = input('enter a word:')
user_word = user_word.upper()

for letter in user_word:
    if letter in ('A','E','I','O','U'):
        continue
    print(letter)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
word_without_vowels = ""
vowels = 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'

user_word = input('enter a word:')
user_word = user_word.upper()

for letter in user_word:
    if letter in vowels:
        continue
    word_without_vowels += letter
print(word_without_vowels)
```