# Deleting Occurences of Vowels in String

Tags: python, string, algorithm

I'm trying to make a program that deleted all vowels from a string but for some reason it is not working. Here is my code in python 3

```
s = list(input())

vowels = ["A", "E", "I", "O", "U", "Y", "a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "y"]

for i in s:
    if i in vowels:
        s.remove(i)
```

The code works except for when two vowels are adjacent to each other since it skips and iteration.
Please let me know if any of you have any ideas on how I could solve this small issue, thanks!

Comment: `s = s.remove(i)`? Also, don't delete while iterating. Better use a list comprehension or regular expression.

Comment: Also see [Remove specific characters from a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3939361/7851470)

Answer (score 5):

Using list comprehension and `join`

```
s = 'Hello world!'
vowels = 'AEIOUYaeiouy'
print(''.join([l for l in s if l not in vowels]))

>>> Hll wrld!
```

Answer (score 5):

The often-overlooked [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) is blazingly fast for this. To only delete characters, you can build a translation table using just the third argument of [`maketrans()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) If you are dealing with more than tiny text, it may be a better option over a regex:

```
removeVowels = str.maketrans("","",'AEIOUYaeiouy')
s = "Hello There"
s.translate(removeVowels)
#'Hll Thr'
```

Comment: This one definitely wins. More than 10 times faster than any rival answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using `re`

```
import re

s = input()
vowels = ["A", "E", "I", "O", "U", "Y", "a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "y"]

print(re.sub('|'.join(vowels), '', s)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you can do:

```
s = input()

vowels = ["A", "E", "I", "O", "U", "Y", "a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "y"]

s = ''.join([i for i in s if i not in vowels])
```

Answer (score 1):

This uses Regex to solve your problem.

```
import re

s = input()
results = re.sub(r'[AEIOUYaeiouy]', '', s)
```

> The syntax of `re.sub()` is:
>
> `re.sub(regex_pattern, replacement, input_string)` 
> The method returns a string where
> matched occurrences are replaced with the content of `replacement` variable.