# How can I delete a specific character from set of tuples?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples, strip

I want to delete points(".") at the end of every word.

My code looks like this:

```
a = [('hello.',0) , ('foji.',0),('you',0)]
print([s.strip('.') for s in a])
```

The output should look something like: `[('hello',0) , ('foji',0), ('you',0)]`

I get an error says tuple object has no attribute strip! even if i use lists instead i get the same error !

note : using replace doesn't work too.

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: it doesnt work with replace too!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove specific characters from a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939361/remove-specific-characters-from-a-string-in-python)

Comment: Think it through. When you iterate with `for s in a`, what do the `s` values look like? What kind of thing are they? Can you `.strip()` that? What is the thing you actually want to call `.strip()` on? Given the `s` value, how do you access that thing? Now, can you figure out the rule to create the desired elements?

Comment: i already tried that. it doesnt work

Comment: To close voters: this is not a duplicate. The problem is not with the logic for manipulating the string; the problem is **accessing** the string.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel indexing a tuple is as duplicate as it gets

Comment: It's not a duplicate *of what was marked*. And the issue is that OP needs to combine a few concepts - indexing the tuple, applying the transformation to the appropriate part of the tuple, creating the new tuple from there, and wrapping it all up in a comprehension - as in the accepted answer. It's maybe not the best "reference" question for future search-engine users, but it's certainly a reasonably original question.

Comment: how is a list of tuples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  a = [('hello.',0) , ('foji.',0),('you',0)]
  print([(s[0].replace('.', ''), s[1]) for s in a])
```

Output:

```
  [('hello', 0), ('foji', 0), ('you', 0)]
```

Answer (score 3):

You are working with tuples inside the list so
every element is (element1,element2)
change your print to

```py
print([(s[0].strip('.'),s[1]) for s in a])
```