# Splitting a string to certain length Python

Tags: python, string, list, split, slice

I have a string I'd like to split to new strings which will contain only text (no commas, spaces, dots etc.). The length of each new string must be of variable n. The slicing must go through each possible combination.
Meaning, for example, an input of  `func('banana pack', 3)` will result in ['ban','ana','nan','ana',pac','ack'].
So far what I managed to achieve is:

```
  def func(text, n):
text = text.lower()
text = text.translate(str.maketrans("", "", " .,"))
remainder = len(text) % n
split_text = [text[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(text) - remainder, n)]
if remainder > 0:
    split_text.append(text[-n:])
print(split_text, len(split_text))
result_dict = {}
for word in split_text:
    if word not in result_dict:
        result_dict[word] = n / len(text)
    else:
        result_dict[word] = (result_dict[word] + 1) / len(text)
return result_dict
```

Comment: why the last elem of the result is "ack" ?

Comment: @DorianTurba I'm guessing that there always has to be three letters in each string.

Comment: For me, the question need improvments

Comment: The length of the strings must always be the size of n

Answer (score 1):

[Get rid of the disallowed characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3939381/5923139) then [chunk the string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475241/split-string-every-nth-character):

```py
def func(text, n):
    text = text.translate(str.maketrans("", "", " .,"))
    return [text[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(text), n)]
```

If you want the last element to always have 3 characters, use this instead:

```py
def func(text, n):
    text = text.translate(str.maketrans("", "", " .,"))
    extra = len(text) % 3
    chunks = [text[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(text) - extra, n)]
    if extra > 0:
        chunks.append(text[-n:])
    return chunks
```