# Split list by comma in python unless surrounded by quotes in python

Tags: python, split, python-re

If I have a string that I want to split where the commas are, how can I exclude any substring surrounded by quotes?

Ex.

> Input: 'a,b,3,"d,e",f,"e,xam,p,le,"]
>
> Output: ['a', 'b', '3', 'd,e', 'f', 'e,xam,p,le,']

using .split(',') doesn't work because it doesn't exclude items in the quotes,
and I'm not sure how I would use re.split() since there can be anything inside of the quotes. There is no set length of the substring or location where a comma could be. I'm asking to try to avoid unnecessary for loops if possible!

Thanks!

Comment: Unless you want to write a state machine that keeps track of open quotes and parses character-by-character (you don't, because you want to "avoid unnecessary for loops if possible"), use the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader)

Comment: You can refer to this as well https://stackoverflow.com/a/3939381/15299683

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of the `csv` module for parsing your data. As you have a string and not a file, you can use `io.StringIO` to obtain a file-like object.

The code would simply be:

```
import csv
from io import StringIO


reader = csv.reader(StringIO('a,b,3,"d,e",f,"e,xam,p,le,"'))
out = next(reader)

print(out)
# ['a', 'b', '3', 'd,e', 'f', 'e,xam,p,le,']
```