# How to remove certain character from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have pandas dataframe like this:

```
api_url
"url": "https://apis.asia.pntk.cloud/asiaerState",
"url": "https://apis.asia.pntk.cloud/M6518&=38396885",
"url": "https://apis.asia.pntk.cloud/=38396885"
"url": "https://apis.asia.pntk.cloud/518112A",
```

In the values there could be ',' at the end. I want to trip all special character, take only the actual api url, so the output dataframe would like this:

```
api_url
https://apis.asia.pntk.cloud/asiaerState
https://apis.asia.pntk.cloud/M65181150%-48UXM%2CNA&so85
https://apis.asia.pntk.cloud/96885
https://apis.asia.pntk.cloud/5181150%2CC9300-48UXM%2A
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove specific characters from a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939361/remove-specific-characters-from-a-string-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hi, You can try this one. it will solve your Issue.**

```
d = {'api_url': ['"url": "https://apis.asia.pntk.cloud/asiaerState"',
'"url": "https://apis.asia.pntk.cloud/M65181150%-48UXM%2CNA&solutionId=38396885",',
'"url": "https://apis.asia.pntk.cloud/CNA&solutionId=38396885"',
'"url": "https://apis.asia.pntk.cloud/5181150%2CC9300-48UXM%2CNA"']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

**Input:**

```
                                             api_url
0  "url": "https://apis.asia.pntk.cloud/asiaerState"
1  "url": "https://apis.asia.pntk.cloud/M65181150...
2  "url": "https://apis.asia.pntk.cloud/CNA&solut...
3  "url": "https://apis.asia.pntk.cloud/5181150%2...
```

**Solution:**

```
df['api_url'] = df['api_url'].str.replace('"',"").replace(',',"").str.lstrip("url: ")
```

**Output:**

```
                                             api_url
0           https://apis.asia.pntk.cloud/asiaerState
1  https://apis.asia.pntk.cloud/M65181150%-48UXM%...
2  https://apis.asia.pntk.cloud/CNA&solutionId=38...
3  https://apis.asia.pntk.cloud/5181150%2CC9300-4...
```