# Stripping characters from the middle of a string

Tags: python

I know you can strip out white spaces from a string. For example:

```
abc = " hello everyone "
cba = abc.strip()
print(cba) # output would be "hello everyone" with no spaces either side
```

However, is it possible to strip characters out of a string?
my first initial guess was:

```
eee = "hello everyone"
rrr = eee.strip(l)
```

In which I was hoping for the output to be "heo world", but I was met with an error instead

I have also tried replacing.

```
strip
```

with:

```
remove
```

But still, no luck.

Comment: `eee.replace("l", "")`

Comment: are you looking for `'hello'.replace('l', '')`?

Comment: Read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) of `strip`.

Comment: `rrr = eee.strip(l)` That's wrong for two reasons.  First, `l` isn't in quotes, so it treats `l` as a variable name.  Second, `strip()` only removes leading/trailing characters, and the L's are in the middle.

Comment: Yes that works! thank you so much @RJAdriaansen

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove specific characters from a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939361/remove-specific-characters-from-a-string-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [`replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=replace#str.replace) method. So for your example, it'd be:

```py
greeing = "hello everyone"
replaced_version = greeting.replace("l", "")
replaced_version # returns 'heo everyone'
```