# Trouble writing function to remove prefixes in Python

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I'm trying to write a function that will remove a prefix from every element of a column in a pandas dataframe. I've made a few attempts but none have seemed to work:

```
prefixes = ['mm10---', 'GRCh38-']
def clean_genes(column):
    for gene in CTRL_data[f'{column}']:
        for prefix in prefixes:
            if row[f"{column}"].str.startswith(f"{prefix}"):
                gene = str.replace(f"{prefix}", '', gene)
    return column

def clean_genes(column):
    for gene in CTRL_data[f"{column}"]:
        gene = gene[7:]
    return column

clean_genes(gene)
```

Could someone point out where these attempts have gone wrong, or how I could better write this function? The error in both cases is:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/pg/d3z5dn_x0f51tlwtj7391tjh0000gn/T/ipykernel_10029/2341573264.py in <module>
     16     return column
     17 
---> 18 clean_genes(gene)

NameError: name 'gene' is not defined
```

EDIT:
I've also looked at some other questions on this site and others, including this one which I thought was helpful ([Remove specific characters from a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939361/remove-specific-characters-from-a-string-in-python)).

Comment: `gene` isn't defined outside of the `clean_genes` function. Also, you have 2 functions named `clean_genes`.

Comment: `clean_genes(gene)` where's `gene` defined?

Comment: what is unclear about `name 'gene' is not defined`?

Comment: @Julien 'gene' is the name of the column in my dataframe. Wouldn't this be more or less equivalent to writing ```column=gene```?

Comment: @Adid the two functions were separate attempts - I hashed out one when running the other

Comment: No that's not how it works. Variable name `gene` and string `'gene'` are not the same thing. Computers don't understand 'more or less'...

Answer (score 2):

If your question actually is "how to remove a number of prefixes from a Pandas dataframe series", then I'd maybe say

1. [create a regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/re.html#re.compile) to match those prefixes
2. use [`.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html#pandas.Series.str.replace) on those series

This will likely be a lot faster than a manual loop too.

```
import re
prefixes = ['mm10---', 'GRCh38-']

# Build a regexp that matches either of the given prefixes, anchored
# to the start of the string.
prefix_re = re.compile("^(" + "|".join(re.escape(prefix) for prefix in prefixes) + ")")

df["my_series"] = df["my_series"].str.replace(prefix_re, "")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the prefix by building regular expression that matches either of your prefixes and then use the regex to replace them with empty string like this:

```
re = r'^(mm10\-\-\-|GRCh38\-)'
df["my_series"] = df["my_series"].str.replace(re, "")
```

Comment: `-` is not a special character in regexps outside a character class and doesn't need to be escaped.