# How to remove an extra dot (.) character in email address by Python?

Tags: python

I would like to find a solution to remove an extra dot in the email address.

e.g. apple@yahoo..com ===> apple@yahoo.com

How to remove the extra dot after the word 'yahoo'?

Comment: `s.replace('..','.')`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove specific characters from a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939361/remove-specific-characters-from-a-string-in-python)

Comment: Why though? If it's to correct typos made by users, this is a hopeless quest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove duplicated dots, I would suggest a regex replace:

```py
email = 'apple@yahoo..com'
email = re.sub(r'[.]{2,}', '.', email)
print(email)  # apple@yahoo.com
```

The regex pattern `[.]{2,}` targets two or more continuous dots, and then we replace with just a single dot.

Comment: Perhaps there could be say 3 dots in a sequence?  In that case, my answer also has this covered.

Comment: instead of `r'[.]{2,}'` you also can use `r'[.]+'` for the same effect

Comment: @Silver not the same effect.  If only one dot, we don't need to do the replacement.

Comment: This is great because it's not limited to the domain and therefore resolves, for example, a..b@mail..com

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen so both do give same result as "." -> "." and "....." -> "." , that same effect to me, just different detailed behavior.

Comment: @Silver ... my version avoids the replacement on a single dot.  It is just a minor optimization.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen true, `+` is equivalent to `{1,}` but with shorter syntax. I think it worth to be mentioned to regex newbie.

Comment: Escaping with `[.]` is not exactly the same as escaping with `\.`, and the former is not really meant to escape characters. It's ok to use it (not a big performance issue), and it's probably optimized into `\.` by the `re` module anyways, but still in a canonical answer I would suggest escaping it properly.

Answer (score 0):

a simple solution for that is to use the method .replace, as below

```
myString = "john.doe@yahoo..com"
myString.replace("..com", ".com")
```

Comment: What about emails which don't use the `.com` domain?

Answer (score 0):

Based on Tim's answer:
(it's more general: it replaces multiple dots in an address)
To me, it's much more readable:
`\.` matches a dot, `+` means "one or more times"

Anyway: to practice with regex I tstrongly suggest visiting [regexr.com](https://regexr.com) it has a nice test field and it explain the syntax giving also a reference

```py
email = 'apple@yahoo..com'
email = re.sub(r'\.+', '.', email)
print(email)  # apple@yahoo.com
```

If you want to only check the multiple dot pattern in the second part of the address (preserve multiuple dots in the sender) you could use

```py
email = 'dds..apple@yahoo..com'
email = re.sub(r'\.+(?=\w+$)', '.', email)
print(email)  # dds..apple@yahoo.com
```

here `\.+`  matches one or more dots, but only if followed (positive lookaround `(?=<pattern>)`) by a alphanumeric sequence `\w+` then by the end of the string `$`