# how can I remove more than one character from a list?

Tags: python, function, replace, typeerror, special-characters

I have a list (new in this, not know how to call it) and want to remove some characters from it but for some reason the function replace() pops a TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

```
lists = <div class="d-map" itemprop="geo" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/GeoCoordinates"><meta content="29.028856" itemprop="latitude"/><meta content="-110.955923" itemprop="longitude"/><div id="map" style="height: 230px;"></div></div>

char_remove = ["<", ">","[", "]", "=", ":", "/" ]
for char in char_remove:
    list = lists.replace(char, " ")
```

Comment: You are replacing in `lists`, and returing in `list`. Only the _last_ replacement gets retained.

Comment: Did you mean: `lists = lists.replace(char, " ")`?

Comment: and you're missing the quotes around `lists = '<div class="d-map" ite...'`

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name, it's the name of a built-in type.

Comment: Your code is wrong, but I don't see how it could be causing the error you show. Nothiing here does `lists.replace = None`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove specific characters from a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939361/remove-specific-characters-from-a-string-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [RegEx](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) for such a case because it can do the same without the need for a loop.

```py
import re


lists = '<div class="d-map" itemprop="geo" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/GeoCoordinates"><meta content="29.028856" itemprop="latitude"/><meta content="-110.955923" itemprop="longitude"/><div id="map" style="height: 230px;"></div></div>'

result = re.sub(r'[<>\[\]=:\/]', '', lists)
```

Result:

```
'div class"d-map" itemprop"geo" itemscope"" itemtype"httpschema.orgGeoCoordinates"meta content"29.028856" itemprop"latitude"meta content"-110.955923" itemprop"longitude"div id"map" style"height 230px;"divdiv'
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your variable *lists* (not a great name in this context) is a string then:

```
lists = """lists = <div class="d-map" itemprop="geo" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/GeoCoordinates"><meta content="29.028856" itemprop="latitude"/><meta content="-110.955923" itemprop="longitude"/><div id="map" style="height: 230px;"></div></div>"""

char_remove = set('<>[]=:/') # the characters that we don't want

print(''.join(c for c in lists if c not in char_remove))
```